# Entity Framework não está interpretando as minhas configurações

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou com um problema sério com o **Entity Framework**.

Tenho duas Tabelas: `Módulos` e `Viaturas`, ambas com a nome da chave primária ID (`Database First`).

Uma viatura pode ter um Módulo, mas também pode ser nulo, a associação não é obrigatória, no entanto tenho uma FK na Tabela `Viaturas` para a Tabela `Módulos`, resumindo as Tabelas foram criadas assim:

```
CREATE TABLE MODULOS
(
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_MODULOS PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE VIATURAS
(
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL,

    PLACA VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,

    ID_MODULO NUMBER,

    CONSTRAINT PK_VIATURAS PRIMARY KEY (ID),

    CONSTRAINT FK_VIATURAS1 FOREIGN KEY (ID_MODULO) REFERENCES MODULOS (ID)
);
```

Tentei fazer o relacionamento de diversas formas, sempre sem sucesso no Entity.

Usando apenas `Data Annotations`...

Classe Modulo:

```
[Table("MODULO")]
public partial class Modulo
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID", TypeName = "NUMBER")]
    public long ModuloID { get; set; }

    public virtual Viatura Viatura { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Viatura:

```
[Table("VIATURA")]
public partial class Viatura
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Modulo")]
    [Column("ID", TypeName = "NUMBER")]
    public long ViaturaID { get; set; }

    [Column("PLACA", TypeName = "VARCHAR2")]
    public string Placa { get; set; }

    [Column("ID_MODULO", TypeName = "NUMBER")]
    public long? ModuloID { get; set; }

    public virtual Modulo Modulo { get; set; }
}
```

Quando eu executo a consulta, o Entity não realiza a comparação

```
VIATURA.ID_MODULO = MODULO.ID
```

Em vez disso, realiza:

```
VIATURA.ID = MODULO.ID

FROM "VIATURA" "Extent1"
INNER JOIN "MODULO" "Extent2" ON "Extent1"."ID" = "Extent2"."ID"
```

Usando apenas Fluent API:

Config Modulo:

```
HasKey(t => t.ModuloID);

Property(b => b.ModuloID).HasColumnName("ID");
```

Config Viatura:

```
HasKey(c => c.ViaturaID);

Property(p => p.ViaturaID).HasColumnName("ID");

HasOptional(t => t.Modulo);
```

Quando eu executo a consulta, o Entity também realiza a comparação:

```
VIATURA.ID = MODULO.ID
```

Forçando a coluna ID_MODULO para o relacionamento no Fluent API:

Config Viatura:

```
HasKey(c => c.ViaturaID);

Property(p => p.ViaturaID).HasColumnName("ID");

HasRequired(h => h.Modulo).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("ID_MODULO"));
```

Config Modulo:

```
HasKey(t => t.ModuloID);

Property(b => b.ModuloID).HasColumnName("ID");
```

Neste cenário, o relacionamento funcionou, mas então o Entity pirou, ele agora acha que a coluna ID da Tabela VIATURA se chama ViaturaID, sendo que eu falei que o nome da coluna é ID.

> {"ORA-00904: \"Extent2\".\"Viatura_ViaturaID\": identificador
>   inválido"}

Estou usando a versão mais atual do Entity (6.2.0) no Dotnet Framework 4.5.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não é a solução mas pode ajudar a melhorar o entendimento do seu codigo, tente mapear as tabelas  com EntityTypeConfiguration, você está fazendo uma  mistura de fluenteApi  com DataNotations ta meio complexo isso ai.

Comment: ForeignKey("Modulo")] é chave estrangeira de ModuloID e não de ID de Viatura.

Comment: Não Marcos, eu fiz separado, primeiro fiz apenas com Data Annotation e depois apenas com Fluent API.

Comment: Descobri o problema, mas não entendi.

Da classe Modulo, eu retirei a declaração:

public virtual Viatura Viatura { get; set; }

E funcionou.

Mas eu entendo que a declaração pode ser nas duas vias (classes), pois eu posso querer selecionar um Modulo e também retornar a Viatura associada.

Comment: @AlbertoLuizSchaub o relacionamento do Entity é sempre feito em uma das duas entidades. Isso é uma regra. Contudo isso não te impede de navegar de forma diferente. Ou seja: Você faz a relação uma única vez e utiliza da forma de quiser.

Answer (score 0):

[ForeignKey("Modulo")] é chave estrangeira de ModuloID e não de ID de Viatura.

```
[Table("VIATURA")]
public partial class Viatura
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID", TypeName = "NUMBER")]
    public long ViaturaID { get; set; }

    [Column("PLACA", TypeName = "VARCHAR2")]
    public string Placa { get; set; }

    [Column("ID_MODULO", TypeName = "NUMBER")]
    [ForeignKey("Modulo")]
    public long? ModuloID { get; set; }

    public virtual Modulo Modulo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado André, pela resposta.

Eu já fiz isso, inclusive tentei muitas outras coisas, fazendo o que você pediu ocorre o erro:

"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nViatura_Modulo_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Viatura_Modulo_Source' in relationship 'Viatura_Modulo'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'

Comment: ModuloID deve ser long e não nullable.

Comment: public virtual Viatura Viatura { get; set; } => public virtual IList<Viatura> Viaturas { get; set; }